# How to use Twitter Bootstrap with panels?

Tags: 7, panels, theming

I am using D7 to built a new site. I am using Twitter Boostrap to create responsive themeing in my site. But most of my design has to be built with panels, the panels does not work responsive with the twitter bootstrap. I found that adaptive theme can be used with panels to make it responsive, But my requirement is to use twitter bootstrap for responsive themeing.

Is there an chance by which I can make the panels responsive with the twitter bootstrap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Panels Bootstrap Layouts](http://drupal.org/project/panels_bootstrap_layouts) module.

Answer (score 2):

If you already are using twitter bootstrap only need create you own layout plugins with bootstrap's fluid layout scaffold.

[Check my example module](https://github.com/capy/Twitter-bootstrap-Drupal-Panels-layout). its functional and has two ports made at this moment but the intention its make a full port of Panels layout plugins.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using panels and specifically panopoly i would check out [Kalatheme](https://drupal.org/project/kalatheme)

Comment: don't post the same answer exactly.